# Switching an HTML feature on and off with a JavaScript/jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, toggle

I have an HTML feature (falling objects) which consists of the following:

```
<div id="elementsToScroll">
            <marquee behavior=scroll direction=down scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=43 height=581 style='position:absolute; left:17%; top:23px; width:100; height:581px;'><font></font></marquee>
</div>
```

and this button:

```
      <button onclick="onOffScroll()">Grapes</button>
```

I'm trying to make the button switch the feature on and off with the following javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function onOffScroll() {
        var x = document.getElementById('elementsToScroll');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }}
 });
```

Please help me identify why it isn't working (or if there's a better way to do it).

(I'm aware falling objects is obsolete, but that isn't the point - I'd like to get the toggle feature working so it can be switched on or off at will). Thanks :)

Scripts:

```
<!--Scripts-->
<script src="/js/myjQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Well you have extra }) in your Javascript code so I am guessing you left out something important. Is there a document.ready code around your function?

Comment: And there we go document.ready makes the function not in global scope....remove the document.ready, it is not necessary here.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I just tried taking it out - but to no effect. When is it necessary?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're looking for jQuery since the code you posted is using plain JavaScript. Here is two examples of how to do this with and without jquery:

**JQuery way (as @Dylan Anlezark mentioned**)

```
function onOffScroll() {
    $('#elementsToScroll').toggle();
}
```

**Plain JavaScript Way**

```
function onOffScroll() {
    var x = document.getElementById('elementsToScroll');

    if (isVisible(x)) {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function isVisible(element) {
    return element.offsetWidth !== 0 && !element.offsetHeight !== 0;
}
```

Assuming your HTML is setup the way you posted it, you don't need to change anything except the function code for `onOffScroll`

```
<div id="elementsToScroll">
        <marquee behavior=scroll direction=down scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=43 height=581 style='position:absolute; left:17%; top:23px; width:100; height:581px;'><font></font></marquee>
    </div>
    <button onclick="onOffScroll()">Grapes</button>
```

Comment: So just to clarify, would I use *either* the jQuery or JavaScript, but add the function code in both cases? 
Would I need to add anything else to the .js document, or just the above?
I have tried several combinations but nothing is doing the trick. Someone suggested testing on a server (instead of locally) but most of my JS does work locally when tested...
Appreciate your time

Comment: It would be either/or. If you went the plain javascript way, just delete your current onOffScroll() function and replace it with the full JS snippet and it'll work. If you wanted to use jQuery, do the same with the jQuery snippet. If you chose to got the jQuery route, make sure you have a reference to the jQuery library within your page. If you don't, then it won't work. If you update your code I can look and see where you're going wrong but the above should work without any issues.

Comment: In addition, take a look at your console (press F12) and see if there are any errors. If there is, let me know what that error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    $("elementsToScroll").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    $("elementsToScroll").toggle();
});
```

works but you would need to use jQuery

Comment: Sorry, slow internet connection 

Comment: Thanks, but there is still no effect. I think I am using jQuery - I also tried specifying the button's ID and using that ($("#onOff") )

Comment: Are you testing on a server or local file? Sometimes those features don't work unless it is on a server (I believe it is a security feature)

Comment: Hmm, I am testing locally, but all the other JavaScript I've tried so far has worked locally if it was going to work at all... Currently seeing if it's possible to test on a server though

Comment: I think it is just for jQuery. jQuery never works for me locally

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `toggle` method should do it.

```
$(function() {
    var elm = $('#elementsToScroll');
    $('.grapes').on('click', function() {
        elm.toggle();
    });
});
```

No need to use inline JavaScript on the button:

```
<button type="button" class="grapes">Grapes</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var elm = $('#elementsToScroll');
    $('.grapes').on('click', function() {
        elm.toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elementsToScroll">
            <marquee behavior=scroll direction=down scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=43 height=581 style='position:absolute; left:17%; top:23px; width:100; height:581px;'><font></font></marquee>
</div>
<button type="button" class="grapes">Grapes</button>
```